# Is closed unit disk in $R^2$ be a vector space ?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The closed unit disk i.e {$x\in R^2:" ||x||_2\leqslant1$} in $R^2$ is not a vector space over the field $R$ with respect to usual addition and point wise multiplication, where $R$ is the set of all real number. Is it possible to define other internal and external composition on the closed unit disk in $R^2$ for which closed unit disk will be a vector space over the field $R$. Give me some hint.

Comment: Clearly not a vector space, since you would have $(0,1) + (0,1)=(0,2)$, so it isn't closed under the usual addition as $(0,2)$ is not in the unit disk. What is "point wise multiplication" of elements of $\mathbb R^2$? Do you mean "component-wise"?

Comment: @MPW That I know. It is not my question.

Comment: @MPW pointwise means $c(a,b)=(ca,cb)$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read carefully. You stated that, and are asking about alternate operations. Gotcha. My bad.

Comment: Okay, so you were just describing the usual vector addition and scalar multiplication. Not sure why I didn't pick up on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914804/vector-space-of-continuous-0-1-0-1-over-r/914846#914846

Comment: Certainly it's possible simply by cardinality. Take a bijection with a finite dimensional vector space. Would you require it to respect the topology?

Comment: ... if so, a nontrivial topological vector space over $\mathbb R$ is never compact.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what if we consider the open unit disc?

Comment: @crf the open unit disc is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: ... if so, $\mathbf{R}$ is non-archimedean. ;-)

Comment: @MattSamuel how do I define the composition?